# Is there an Numpy way of combining arrays based on their timestamp row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

By their timestamp, I want to combine 2 arrays with shapes (3, 6) and (3, 8), respectively.

here is the original array:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

i have extracted the values with ones:

```
res = np.where(a[0] == 1)
ones = a[:,res].squeeze()
zeros = np.delete(a,res,axis=1)

zeros
(3, 8)
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  8,  9, 10, 11]])

ones
(3, 6)
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Now i want to combine them again by their last row, which is the timestamp.

Is there any numpy solution to that?

Expected result:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Comment: are you looking for `np.hstack((zeros, ones))`?

Comment: not exactly. i want to hstack it based on the last row(i want it sorted on the last row). i can just sort it but I am planning to do it on a huge array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the ideas from both users [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962634/11055992) and [Epsi95](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68962359/11055992), this solved my problem so far. Yet, I'm still open to more performant solutions.

```
m =np.hstack((zeros, ones))
a = m[:, m[2, :].argsort()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way (probably not the most compact however):

```
m = np.hstack((zeros, ones))
m2 = list(zip(m[2], m[0], m[1]))
m2.sort()
np.roll(m2, -1, axis=-1).T
```